# Projection onto a subspace in an $L_p$ normed space

Tags: lp-spaces, normed-spaces, angle, projection, gram-schmidt

I am trying to write down the angle between two $1$-dimensional and $t$-dimensional subspaces of a normed space $L_p$. In particular, I am following Milicic's [On the Gram-Schmidt Projection in Normed Spaces](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43666363?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents). There, Eq. 6 defines the Gram-Schmidt projection of a vector $x\in X$ on the subspace $Y=\text{span}\{y_1\dots y_n\}$ as:

$$
\bar{x} = - \frac{1}{\Gamma(y_1\dots y_n)} \begin{vmatrix}
0 & y_1 & \dots & y_n\\
g(y_1, x) & g(y_1,y_1) & \dots & g(y_1, y_n) \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots  \\
g(y_n, x) & g(y_n,y_1) & \dots & g(y_n, y_n)
\end{vmatrix}
$$
where $\Gamma(\cdot)$ is the Gram-determinant and $g(\cdot)$ is the semi-inner product. $|\cdot|$ is a determinant sign. **Here I do not understand how this calculation can yield a vector**. The same notation exists in follow-up papers and as a non-mathematician I am feeling like I am missing some conventions.

Comment: Since the top row of the "determinant" consists of vectors rather than scalars, I would assume you're supposed to interpret this by "expanding" the determinant along the top row.  That gives you a linear combination of $y_1, \dots, y_n$, which will indeed be a vector.

Comment: This is precisely my question. Could you elaborate more on what you would mean by "expanding" ?

Comment: Just the usual [expansion by minors](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeterminantExpansionbyMinors.html); the very first method you learn in high school.  Frankly I'm trying to explain it without writing it out in full because I am too lazy to TeX that many $\cdots$s.

Comment: Oh I see interesting. Thanks.